# Get image by name

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use the value from a neighbouring cell as a variable inside an image link, but something goes wrong.

Can someone help me?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BS4Ow-KOqqlFYAtqiyqOO--wL5B1lqm5srN8pjldKg0/edit?usp=sharing

fx: `=IMAGE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE("https://cdn.dota2.net/item/";A3;"/300.png"), " ", "%20"))`

Comment: Please write more detail here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `;` to `&` and then change `,` to `;`

```
=IMAGE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE("https://cdn.dota2.net/item/"&A3&"/300.png"); " "; "%20"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: didn't help my problem